# How do you delay an async thunk action until after authentication session token has been stored?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, jwt, redux-thunk

I've built an API and I'm trying to fetch data (using axios) and render it into a component in my react-native app (node/express server). I'm using JWT to authenticate my users and react-navigation for screen routing.

I'm successfully authenticating and storing the session token into AsyncStorage. After login, the app navigates to the first screen where I want to show the list of data from my API.

The problem is that the GET request is being executed before the token is saved to AsyncStorage, so I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error.

The execution should be -

1) Authenticate user
2) Render component with fetched data

AHH! I can't figure it out.  Please help? :(

I tried calling the action in lifecycle method componentDidMount, but no success with that.

Here's the parent component:

```
class PlansScreen extends Component {

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarLabel: 'Plans',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="schedule" size={30} color={tintColor} />
    )
});

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <ActivityList/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

export default PlansScreen;
```

Here's the child component I want to render the list of fetched data:
***ignore the fact that I haven't fleshed out this entire component yet, I'm currently trying to just make the API request execute after the session token has saved***

```
class ActivityList extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchActivities();
}


render() {
    // console.log(this.props);
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList 
            //My data will render here
            />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { 
fetchActivities, 
})(ActivityList);
```

Here is the fetchActivities thunk action creator -

```
export const fetchActivities = () => {
return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ACTIVITIES_INITIATE });

        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

        let { data } = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/activities`);

            dispatch({ 
                type: FETCH_ACTIVITIES_SUCCESS,
                payload: data
            });            


            console.log(data);

    } catch(error) { 
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
            // signupUserFail(dispatch);
        };
    };
};
```

Here's my activity list reducer -

```
import {
   FETCH_ACTIVITIES_INITIATE,
   FETCH_ACTIVITIES_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
   activities: null,
   loading: false
 };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ACTIVITIES_INITIATE:
            return { ...state, loading: true };

        case FETCH_ACTIVITIES_SUCCESS:
            return {...state,
                   activities: action.payload,
                   loading: false
                   };        
        default:
            return state;
    }
 };
```

Here's my authentication/login thunk action creator -

```
export const loginUser = ({ userEmail, userPassword, navigation }) => {

return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_INITIATE });

        let { data } = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/users/login`, {
            userEmail, userPassword
        });

        AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
        // AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((res) => console.log(res));

            dispatch({ 
                type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
                payload: data
            });            


            navigation.navigate('Plans');

            console.log(data);
            // console.log(store.getState());

    } catch(error) { 
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            // console.log(error.config);
            loginUserFail(dispatch);
        };
   };
 };
```

and here's my login/auth reducer -

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { 
   userName: '',
   userEmail: '',
   userPassword: '',
   user: null,
   loginError: '',
   signupError: '',
   loading: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    // console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case USERNAME_CHANGED:
            return {...state, userName: action.payload};

        case EMAIL_CHANGED:
            return {...state, userEmail: action.payload};

        case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
            return {...state, userPassword: action.payload};

        case LOGIN_USER_INITIATE:
            return {...state, loading: true, loginError: '', signupError: ''};

        case SIGNUP_USER_INITIATE:
            return {...state, loading: true, loginError: '', signupError: ''};

        case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, 
                user: action.payload, 
                loginError: '', 
                signupError: '', 
                loading: false,
                userPassword: '',
                userEmail: ''
            };

        case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
            return { ...state, loginError: 'Authentication failed!', userPassword: '', loading: false };

        case SIGNUP_USER_FAIL:
            return { ...state, signupError: 'Signup failed!', userPassword: '', loading: false };

        default: 
            return state;
   }
};
```

this.props.fetchActivities is being called before the token is saved!

I've been trying to figure this out for hours!! Would really appreciate any help, even if it's just to lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe `await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token);`?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response @Oblosys! I tried adding await but I'm still having the same issue. Makes me think it could be something unrelated to when the token is being saved. The mystery continues :l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... I figured out what I did wrong and I feel so ridiculous for not realizing sooner x_x  I forgot to add the auth header to the GET request and that's why it wasn't authenticating.

In the fetchActivities action creator, for me it should have been -

```
let { data } = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/activities`, { 
    headers: { 'x-auth': `${token}` } 
});
```

To anyone reading this in the future ----- make sure you added your auth header. Thanks to @Oblosys for his response, which helped me realize it had nothing to do with when the token was being saved.